# Extracting column names (samples) contaning text from another column

Tags: r, bioinformatics

[image]

I want to extract only those Samples which contains alleles2 of SNP1 to 9 and want to put them in a table side by side in a way that I can distinguish which SNP corresponds to which Samples.

My data looks like this:

```
dput(soil)    
structure(list(SNPs = c("SNP1", "SNP2", "SNP3", "SNP4", "SNP5", 
    "SNP6", "SNP7", "SNP8", "SNP9"), alleles = c("C/T", "G/C", "A/C", 
    "G/T", "A/C", "C/A", "T/C", "T/G", "A/G"), alleles1 = c("CC", 
    "GG", "AA", "GG", "AA", "CC", "TT", "TT", "AA"), alleles2 = c("TT", 
    "CC", "CC", "TT", "CC", "AA", "CC", "GG", "GG"), Sample1 = c("CC", 
    "GG", "CA", "TT", "CC", "AA", "CC", "GG", "GG"), Sample2 = c("CC", 
    "GG", "AA", "TG", "CA", "AC", "CT", "GT", "GA"), Sample3 = c("CC", 
    "CC", "AA", "TG", "CA", "AC", "CT", "GT", "GA"), Sample4 = c("CC", 
    "GG", "AA", "GG", "AA", "CC", "TT", "TT", "AA"), Sample5 = c("CC", 
    "GG", "CC", "GG", "AA", "CC", "TT", "TT", "AA"), Sample6 = c("CC", 
    "CG", "AA", "TG", "CA", "AA", "CT", "GT", "GA"), Sample7 = c("CC", 
    "CC", "AA", "GG", "AA", "CC", "TT", "GG", "AA"), Sample8 = c("CC", 
    "GG", "AA", "TT", "CC", "AC", "CT", "GT", "GA"), Sample9 = c("CC", 
    "GG", "AA", "GG", "AA", "AC", "CC", "TT", "AA"), Sample10 = c("TT", 
    "GG", "CA", "TG", "CA", "AC", "TT", "TT", "AA"), Sample11 = c("TT", 
    "GG", "AA", "GG", "AA", "CC", "TT", "TT", "AA"), Sample12 = c("TT", 
    "GG", "CC", "TT", "CC", "AA", "CC", "TT", "GG"), Sample13 = c("TT", 
    "GG", "CA", "TG", "CA", "AC", "TT", "TT", "GG")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -9L))
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you share your data with us so we can help you better? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I have updated my question with dput(). Or you need something else? I am new on this platform.

Comment: @VinodKumar , I just provided an answer; not sure if that is the output format you want or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use data.table to melt the data into long format, and identify which Samples have allele2 for each SNP:

```
library(data.table)
melt(
  setDT(soil)
  ,id.vars = c("SNPs", "alleles2"),
  measure.vars = patterns("Sample."),
  variable.name = "Sample"
)[value==alleles2, .("Samples" = list(Sample)), by=SNPs]
```

Output:

```
     SNPs                             Samples
   <char>                              <list>
1:   SNP4            Sample1,Sample8,Sample12
2:   SNP5            Sample1,Sample8,Sample12
3:   SNP6            Sample1,Sample6,Sample12
4:   SNP7            Sample1,Sample9,Sample12
5:   SNP8                     Sample1,Sample7
6:   SNP9           Sample1,Sample12,Sample13
7:   SNP2                     Sample3,Sample7
8:   SNP3                    Sample5,Sample12
9:   SNP1 Sample10,Sample11,Sample12,Sample13
```

#### Update:

Let's say the column names of the columns representing the "Samples" is not consistent, but rather, they have a whole range of names, like this raw data:

```
   SNPs alleles alleles1 alleles2 yngi mdaj osiw nvzg gfbu avnb rjhe eaug hfgx xrhp zajg zrdj vule
1: SNP1     C/T       CC       TT   CC   CC   CC   CC   CC   CC   CC   CC   CC   TT   TT   TT   TT
2: SNP2     G/C       GG       CC   GG   GG   CC   GG   GG   CG   CC   GG   GG   GG   GG   GG   GG
3: SNP3     A/C       AA       CC   CA   AA   AA   AA   CC   AA   AA   AA   AA   CA   AA   CC   CA
4: SNP4     G/T       GG       TT   TT   TG   TG   GG   GG   TG   GG   TT   GG   TG   GG   TT   TG
5: SNP5     A/C       AA       CC   CC   CA   CA   AA   AA   CA   AA   CC   AA   CA   AA   CC   CA
6: SNP6     C/A       CC       AA   AA   AC   AC   CC   CC   AA   CC   AC   AC   AC   CC   AA   AC
7: SNP7     T/C       TT       CC   CC   CT   CT   TT   TT   CT   TT   CT   CC   TT   TT   CC   TT
8: SNP8     T/G       TT       GG   GG   GT   GT   TT   TT   GT   GG   GT   TT   TT   TT   TT   TT
9: SNP9     A/G       AA       GG   GG   GA   GA   AA   AA   GA   AA   GA   AA   AA   AA   GG   GG
```

Then, if the integer range of the columns of interest is known, one can use that range in the `measure.vars` argument, as below (in this case `5:!7`):

```
library(data.table)
melt(
  setDT(soil)
  ,id.vars = c("SNPs", "alleles2"),
  measure.vars = 5:17,
  variable.name = "Sample"
)[value==alleles2, .("Samples" = list(Sample)), by=SNPs]
```

Output:

```
   SNPs             Samples
1: SNP4      yngi,eaug,zrdj
2: SNP5      yngi,eaug,zrdj
3: SNP6      yngi,avnb,zrdj
4: SNP7      yngi,hfgx,zrdj
5: SNP8           yngi,rjhe
6: SNP9      yngi,zrdj,vule
7: SNP2           osiw,rjhe
8: SNP3           gfbu,zrdj
9: SNP1 xrhp,zajg,zrdj,vule
```

Finally, if remove the non-needed columns, in this case `alleles` and `alleles1`, we can actually do away with the `meaures.vars` argument completely, and `melt`, will just assume `measure.vars` is all the other variables:

```
melt(
  setDT(soil)[, !c("alleles", "alleles1")]
  ,id.vars = c("SNPs", "alleles2"),
  variable.name = "Sample"
)[value==alleles2, .("Samples" = list(Sample)), by=SNPs]
```

Comment: it looks good.  Your suggestion is working absolutely fine when column names are same but I could not use it when thousands of column names are completely different. Could you also write something for that? Thanks,

Comment: @VinodKumar do you mean that the names "Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3", etc, are not consistent?  For example, might they be "x", "x2", "y", "z", "abc", "lkjdkf", etc?

Comment: yes exactly. In some of the files, column names are completely different.

Comment: I've made an edit that relies on the at least having the integer range of the columns of interest

Comment: i also showed how you could do this by simply ignoring measure.vars altogether, by removing the non-needed variables.. Then `melt` will simply use all the variables that aren't in `id.vars`

Comment: thank you very much. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: I can see the results as list in R but writing an output or editing it for further work is a big issue. I can't export it as the list contains factors and levels. Do you have a suggestion for that or I should post a new question for that?

Comment: I agree, list columns are hard to deal with.. I would keep it in long format, which can be done by ending with `[value==allleles2]` instead of the current call